# A Book About Humans Escaping Earth To Land On A Planet Inhabited by Flying Bug-Aliens

Tags: story-identification

I read this book in around 4th grade, in the mid 2000's. My memories of it are very vague, but I remember it consisting of a large group of humans leaving Earth on a ship to search for another home planet. I believe something was wrong with Earth, forcing them to leave.

The colonists on the ship specifically have rabbits to raise as livestock. They land on a planet filled with giant boulders, as well as jellyfish. They begin to burn the jellyfish in place of kerosene to light their lanterns. Eventually, it turns out that the boulders are actually bug-like aliens who fly upwards and fill the sky.

My memories of the end of the book are a bit vague. I remember the human colonists deciding to take "sleeping pills", which I assumed was a euphemism for suicide.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you happen to remember any details of the cover art, or even just the overall colour?  Did you get the book from your school, a public library, or was it personally owned (by you or a friend)?  How big was the book (format and thickness)?

Comment: @DavidW Hi, thank you! I can't say I remember a lot about the cover art. The book was actually a reading assignment in an advanced reading class (4th or 5th grade, I think). Everyone in the class was given a copy to read. I remember it being a paperback, and it wasn't especially long, I'd say about 200-300 pages. I found it a bit frightening at the time, but I assume it's probably classified as children's or young adult's literature